# Stopping the auto scroll of listview android

Tags: android-widget

I have a listview which has 10 items , only 5 items are visible , View has to be scrolled down to see the rest. Listview by default does autoscroll when I reach the bottom of the view.

But I want to disable this auto scroll as I am having my own implementation of scroll using
listview.setSelection(position);

So the question is how to stop autoscroll in ListView ?

Answer (score 2):

**sdk since 9 has:**

```
listView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

**and see**

[ListView Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223367/listview-scrolling)